# Content and Structure Move Loses Author Information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does anyone know why using the move feature of Content and Structure loses the author information?  If I run it as a Site Collection administrator it completely works as expected but any other user it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be a site collection admin to preserve original owners.

Comment: I am looking for official confirmation of that. I are no reference to this limitation in any of the Microsoft documentation. Seems like a bizarre limitation.

Comment: Not at all - otherwise anybody could move a document to a completely different location and SharePoint would not have tracked who made the change.